# Redirect to an other URL if logged in or logged out

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I'm working on a web site on wordpress.

I have a link on my homepage called  **"SALE"** , I would like people if they are logged in to access to the page **...../my-account/vendre/** and if they are not to the create account page" **..../register/**
I tried this but doesn't work:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'redirect_non_logged_users_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_non_logged_users_to_specific_page() {

if ( !is_user_logged_in() && is_page('my-account_vendre') && 
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' ) {

wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.dev/register' ); 
exit;
}
}
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Create `$_SESSION` variable if user is logged like `$_SESSION['isloged']` and then you can check in if this variable is set. If it is set the show the button with redirect to `...../my-account/vendre/` else redirect to `..../register/`